# Casting integer to character

Tags: pic, c, eeprom

I am using PIC18f microcontroller. I have to write a 16 bit integer variables (2 bytes) which was cast into two character variable i.e to write each byte in a consecutive adrressess of EEPROM. By first I have to write a upper byte(8bit data) in the EEPROM. I am unable to get the higher 8 bit of the integer variable by the following code (where I  am able to write the lower eight bit of the integer variable ). My code is

```
void int_EEPROM_putc(unsigned char address, unsigned char data);
unsigned char int_EEPROM_getc(unsigned char address);
unsigned char c;
unsigned int d;
unsigned char* e;
unsigned char f;

void main()
{
d=0xffff;
e=(unsigned char*)&d;
//f=*e
f=*(e+1);
int_EEPROM_putc(0x02,f); 
delay_ms(100);
c=int_EEPROM_getc(0x02); 
while(true)
{
    if(c==255)
    {
    PORTB=~PORTB;
    }
    else
    {
    PORTB=0xff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you seem to over complicate things, the pointer arithmetic looks correct at a first glance. You expect `c` to be 0xFF, but it isn't?

Comment: And are you sure your EEPROM routines are working at all? How did you verify that with the lower byte? Remember that default EEPROM content is `0xFF`, I would use some initial value like `d=0xAABB;` to differentiate the values.

Comment: ya I have checked the lower byte with other values it works fine @Rev1.0

Comment: What do you have connected to PORTB? LEDs? Since you just toggle that PORT continuously without any delay, you may not be able to see the flickering. Can you use a programmer to read out the EEPROM contents?

Comment: I am using a digital oscilloscope for checking the toggling of the portB

Comment: Well, judging from the code above it would even toggle if the EEPROM write fails since initial content is 0xFF. But I suppose it is not toggling at all? You could write the content of `c` to you port and evaluate the value.

Comment: when a pic doesn't seem to work correctly, I generally find that I have overlooked something in the documentation and some port only does X for N while Y is enabled...

Answer (score 3):

The most general approach for extracting pieces of an integer value is to shift and mask. So:

```
d = whatever;
c = d & 0xff; // extract low 8 bits
c = (d >> 8) & 0xff; // extract next 8 bits
```

If, as here, you know that the value in d is 16 bits, you can make the code for the next 8 bits a little simpler by writing

```
c = d >> 8; // extract high 8 bits of 16-bit value
```

Comment: While this is correct, it does not answer the question why the OPs proposed code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Generally... it's not terrific practice to assume any bit size or "endian-ness" for any int, for portability reasons. Depending upon the processor and the compiler, and int may be anything from 8-bit to 64-bit, or even some other odd size, and may be stored in either little-endian or big-endian format.

What happens if you do either of these two?

```
if(d==255)
{
}

// or 

int d = 0xffff;
d >> 8;
char c = d;
if (c==255)
{
}
```

Comment: I am using MPLAB8.70 and Pic18f45k80. d>>8 is not working, the division operator also not working.

Comment: `d>>8;` will not have any effect. It's purely a right-hand value, not assigned to anything. You probably want `d=d>>8;`

Comment: @Dzarda - good catch; I dropped a character. It SHOULD have been "d>>=8;". Depending upon the compiler, that's often cheaper (in terms of CPU cycles) than "d=d>>8;".

Comment: @TDHofstetter, do you have an actual example of such a compiler? I'd consider it very weird if `d >>= 8;` and `d = d >> 8;` compiled to different code.

Comment: I don't have a specific compiler in mind at the moment, but I do know that some compilers will perform a d>>=8 in-place, shifting the value within the register, while other compilers will shift the value, rewrite the variable into memory, then reread that memory and rewrite it with the same value. Given some little time, I could probably show you three or four compile-to-assembly examples from real-world compilers. I've been optimizing code for a very long time... 8)

Comment: @TDHofstetter: I find that very weird indeed. Perhaps I'm from the generation that relies on modern compilers :)

Comment: Yep, probably. 8) We've forgotten, today, a whole TON of the basics that guys like me had to cut out teeth on - we wrote the precursors of today's compilers. When I started, a lot of the work I did even predated assembly language - we manually wrote machine code, and paid very close attention to every byte and clock cycle because available memory was in kilobytes (or less) and clock speeds were often under 1MHz. It's proved handy - today, I still write extreme-efficiency code because that's what my projects call for.